# UVa problem 458 - The Decoder python runtime error

Tags: python, algorithm

So, this is the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qaVn.png

This is my code.

```
while True:
    try:
        code = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if len(code) == 0:
        continue
    decode = ''
    for i in code:
        decode += chr(ord(i) - 7)

    print(decode)
```

Example Input:

```
[opz'pz'h'x|p{l'zpunsl'wyvislt5
PM'`V\'HYL'YLHKPUN'[OPZ3'`V\'TH`IL'OH]L'MV\UK'[OL'ZVS\[PVU5
Rllw'jvkpun'huk'{yhpupun'{opz'rpuk'vm'wyvisltz5'P['JV\SK'IL'YLHSS`'L_JP[PUN5
Zv555
TH`'[OL'JVKL'IL'^P[O'`V\5
```

Example Output:

```
This is a quite single problem.
IF YOU ARE READING THIS, YOU MAYBE HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION.
Keep coding and training this kind of problems. IT COULD BE REALLY EXCITING.
So...
MAY THE CODE BE WITH YOU.
```

It works just fine but when I submitted to UVa it always gives me runtime error.

What does possibly I do wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: probably your program isn't terminating for some case. Is `if len(code) == 0:continue` necessary ? You might  just stop taking input is such case. `if len(code) == 0:
        break`

Answer (score 0):

I can get AC on the other judge platform and runs very fast, but 'Wrong Anser' on [onliejudge.org](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=399).

```py
    import sys
    s = {k:k-7 for k in range(128)}
    s[10]=10
    s[13]=13
    sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().translate(s))
```

But like your answer, this approach will get stuck in "UnicodeError" because of 'Time limit exceeded'.

```py
    import sys
    while 1:
        s = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if s :
            try:
                print(chr(ord(s)-7),end='')
            except UnicodeError:
                while 1:pass
        else:
            break
```

So I think your code stuck in 'UnicodeError' runtime error too.