# UVa 458 - The Decoder: Python runtime error

Tags: python

Here's my code

```
while True:
    try:
        a = input()
    except EOFError:
        break

    print(''.join([chr(ord(i) - 7) for i in a]))
```

I saw the same question in this website before.

This is the link: [UVa problem 458 - The Decoder python runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897495/uva-problem-458-the-decoder-python-runtime-error)

But it seems doesn't work.
I've tried every thing I know.
It can work on my computer but UVa still give me runtime error.
How should I improve my code?

Thank you.

I've browse all the websites I found, but sadly, it's rare to find the person who solve this problem by Python.

---

I found a weird situation.
I solve this problem by C++ formerly.

This is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;

    while(cin >> s){
        string ans;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            ans += char(int(s[i] - 7));

        cout << ans << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I got "Accept" on online judge.

It seems that using C++ to solve this problem doesn't have to consider the details mentioned below.
How's that happened?

Comment: What is UVa? And can you post the error message in it's entirety?

Comment: UVa is the online judge website.
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=0&problem=399&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+28008143
And it wouldn't tell me the detailed message when I get wrong.
It just said that I got runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

So the `Python runtime error` comes from `chr(ord(i) - 7)` as `ord(i) - 7` might become negative. If you limit the values to the range (0, 128), this should not produce the error.

I'd assume that encoding is mod128-based, so `chr((ord(i) - 7) % 128)`. Unfortunately, this gives a "Wrong answer" on "online judge".

There's also this part of the task:

> ... the printable portion of the ASCII character set

Which is [32 to 126](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#printable_characters). But the task doesn't specify what to do exactly in case the value is outside of the range, so I thought that it's mod-this range:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = input()
    except EOFError:
        break

    for i in a:
        decode = (ord(i) - 7 - 32) % 94 + 32
        print(chr(decode), end='')
    print()
```

But that also gives a "Wrong answer".

Skipping values that are outside the "printable range" and leaving them unchanged also doesn't work.